# Print file from terminal via smb

Tags: terminal, printing, smb

So UI printing fails with no reason as always.

I hope that I can get more details by printing from command line.

Tried

```
smbutil print //user@host/share file
```

got:

```
smbutil: unknown command print
```

Do I have to install something?

(I have OS X 10.10)

Comment: print is a windows command - look at lpr for Unix printing. Also what app are you printing with - was there anything ion the console. What promter were you printing to

Comment: @Mark thank you for reply. I need to print to smb share, and I don't know what is the "promter". I set up the printer in CUPS, and now there it says: pending since <date> "Unable to connect to server". And I have no idea if the problem is in reaching server or authenticating or whatever else. That's why I wanted to try to use command line which usually in verbose mode can give you a log of 2 A4 pages, where you can find something useful. (I was just printing from Preview with standard OS X stuff)

Comment: I found this for you to try: print [-connection_options] //user@server/share file

Comment: @Buscar웃, yes, but this is part of `smbutil`, right? That's what I was using and it says that the command is unknown

Comment: I assume you have the network share option installed/activated ?

Comment: See also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125577/printing-to-a-windows-printer-from-the-command-line-smbclient-c-print?rq=1 - which implies print is not part of Apple's smbutils - Possibly get a version direct from samba?

Comment: @Mark, `print` is not strictly a windows command; It's also present with the Linux version of smbutils, and it once was included in the OS X version. You are quite correct about `lpr` — this is the command one would use to print from terminal on OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are really looking for is a `smbclient` alternative using `smbutil` but just like you, I couldn't make it work.
So what you can do is to install samba with [homebrew](http://brew.sh/)  like this:

```
brew install samba
```

If `brew link` complains with:

> Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
>   The formula built, but is not symlinked into */usr/local*
>   Could not symlink *lib/auth*
>   /usr/local/lib is not writable.

you can link smbclient manually:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -sfv ../Cellar/samba/3.6.25/bin/smbclient smbclient
sudo chown -R your_user /usr/local/bin/smbclient
```

Now you should be able to print like this:

```
smbclient "\\\\your.server.com\\YourSharedPrinter" -U "Domain\User" -c "print YouFileToPrint"
```

Comment: Doesn't work at the time of this comment. The `samba` package has been removed from brew's core formulae. I tried installing it using `brew install homebrew/boneyard/samba` but that failed too, with the following error: *Error: samba was moved to homebrew-boneyard because it has unfixable issues. Please do not file any issues about this. Sorry!*.