# How to connect to SMB server through terminal?

Tags: macos, command-line, smb

I need the equivalent of Ubuntu's `smbclient` to connect to a SMB server's resources and disconnect. I do not need mounting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need that specific command, [installing it via homebrew](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/181977/5472) might be the best option. For many items, this trio of os supplied commands might do the trick:

```
mount
umount 
mount_smbfs
```

If the manual pages are lacking, feel free to ask a follow on question with additional details.

Comment: Is there a way without mounting? I was supposed to perform an exercise where I need to only connect, and that's all, to the server on ubuntu, but I have to do it on mac.

Comment: Netcat, ssh and python let you connect - depends what the scope of the exercise is I suppose… @Intolighter

Comment: You added reference to samba, that is what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you still need this after 2 years, but for anyone having this problem in 2023 or later, you can install it on macos with: brew install samba. :)

Comment: Keep in mind that you'll need to have Homebrew installed for this.

Comment: Installing via `brew` was mentioned in the accepted answer from 2 years ago. Does your answer bring any new information?